# How to pass touch events from one view to another

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiresponder

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UIView` subview, which has a `UITableView` subview. What I want is for the container scroll view to scroll when the user scrolls on the `UITableView`. Is there a way to pass the touch event from the child `UIScrollView` to the container `UIScrollView`? Thanks for you help. Here is the code for the scroll view. The parent scroll view is created in code, and the subviews are created in IB.

```
CGFloat offset = ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0) ? 64.0 : 44.0;
self.parentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, offset, 320.0, self.view.frame.size.height - offset)];
self.parentScrollView.delegate = self;
self.parentScrollView.bounces = NO;
self.parentScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.header.frame.size.height - offset, 0, 0, 0);
self.parentScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.parentScrollView];

[self.contentView.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PodcastCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PodcastCell"];
[self.contentView.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DescriptionCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DescriptionCell"];
self.contentView.delegate = self;
self.contentView.tableView.delegate = self;
self.contentView.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.parentScrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
self.parentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, self.contentView.frame.size.height);
```

Sorry I didn't explain this very well. I need the parent `UIScrollView` to scroll until the child `UITableView` reaches the top of the parent, at which point the parent `UIScrollView` should stop scrolling, and the child `UItableView` should start scrolling. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` in your `UITableView`, calculate the `contentOffset` then call `setContentOffset:animated:` from your container view.